# Find a number of terms in a series to get a remainder?

Tags: calculus

I have absolutely no idea how to approach this. All I know is the proof, and I can't correlate this to the actual problem. I'm a beginner in calculus and would greatly appreciate your help.

How many terms $N$  of the series 
$$
\sum_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}
$$
can we use to guarantee the number 
$$
R_N = 
\sum_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}
- \sum_{2}^{N} \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}
$$
is less than 0.1?

[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj64R.png)

Comment: Please learn to express your problem using MathJax.  Look at the source of the modified problem by clicking edit, to see how it is written for this one time.  People don't want to have to go to a link to see the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling to figure out how to do Rn so I gave up.

Comment: The assumptions are $\sum_{2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(\ln n)^2}$ converges to V. and each term is positive.  So they are asking what is the smallest possible value of $N$ so that $V - .1 < \sum_{2}^{N} \frac{n}{(\ln n)^2} < V$.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes- can I test this by plugging in values starting at 2?

Comment: or, find V I suppose.@fleablood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to guarantee that 
$$
\sum_{N+1}^\infty \frac1{n(\log n)^2} < 0.1
$$

One good way of doing this is to express the sum as an approximation of an integral, where you know that the sum is less than the integral and you can do the integral exactly.

Consider a rectangle of height  $\frac1{(N+1)(\log (N+1))^2}$ and width going from $x=N$ to $x=N+1$.  That area, which is  $\frac1{(N+1)(\log (N+1))^2}$,  is the first term in your sum, and it also lies completely below the curve 
$y=\frac1{x(\log x)^2}$.

Similarly, take a rectangle of height $\frac1{(N+2)(\log (N+2))^2}$ and width going from $x=N+1$ to $x=N+2$; that area is the second term of your sum and the rectangle also lies below the curve   $y=\frac1{x(\log x)^2}$.

And so forth -- that means that your full sum is less than the area under the curve, which is 
$$
\int_{x=N}^\infty \frac1{x(\log x)^2} dx = \left. -\frac{1}{\log x} \right|_N^\infty = \frac{1}{\log N} 
$$
\log N > 10 
So now we just take $$ \frac{1}{\log N} < 0.1\implies \log N > 10 \implies N > e^{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac 1{n(\ln n)^2}$ is a decreasing function of $n$, whether $n$ is viewed as an integer or as a real.  This allows us to say $$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac 1{n(\ln n)^2} \lt \int_{N}^\infty \frac 1{n(\ln n)^2}dn=\left.-\frac 1{\ln n}\right |_N^\infty=\ln N$$ where we have replaced the term $n$ in the sum with the integral from $n-1$ to $n$ to get the inequality.